# Need ajax call to return json array and execute javascript function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, google-maps

First of all, I should clarify that this is in Wordpress. I'm having trouble returning a json array and executing a javascript function using that json array. I currently have a list of 8 projects in the database. Each project has a title, latitude, longitude, status (complete or incomplete), industry(i.e. oil, petrol, etc.), and state. The ajax call executes based on three dropdown menus for status, industry, and state. The ajax call then creates a new wp_query based on that criteria, and then replaces the list of projects on the page. This all works fine.

However, the list also corresponds to a google map. All projects have markers on the map when the page loads. Whenever the ajax filtering happens, I need to remove and replace those markers with the new listings. This is where I need the json array in order to add the markers to the map. I just can't figure out how to return the json array and then use it in a javascript function to add the markers.

Below is the ajax call:

```
$( "#states" ).change(function() {

        // Get values from all three dropdown menus
        var state = $('#states').val();
        var markets = $('#markets').val();
        var services = $('#services').val();

        $('#project-list').fadeOut();

        // This does the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data: {
                'action' : 'json_info',
                'state' : state,
                'status' : markets,
                'services' : services
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                $('#project-list').html( data );
                $('#project-list').fadeIn();
               // this is where I get lost
               addMarkers(data);

            }   /*,
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }*/
        }); // end of ajax call

    }); // end of click function
```

And in the json_info action, I have the following:

```
function json_info() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

....

    // create a new array to store projects
    $projectsArray = array();

        // query results by page template
        $my_query = new WP_Query($pages);

....        

        if($my_query->have_posts()) : 

                while($my_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $my_query->the_post();  

                    // $projects array is filled with the results of the query loop
                    $projectsArray[] = array(
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'lat' => get_field('latitude'),
                    'long' => get_field('longitude'),
                    'status' => get_field('status'),
                    'industry' => get_field('industry'),
                    'state' => get_field('state')
                    //'num' => $n
                    );  

                    // this outputs each title into a list
                    echo '<li>'.the_title().'</li>';

            endwhile; endif;

         } // end of isset

         ?>

         <script>
                // set jqueryarray before the ajax file in order to parse the PHP, I'm not sure if this is correct???
                var myjsonarray = <?php echo json_encode($projectsArray); ?>;
            </script>

         <?php
         // I'm not sure if this is correct???        
         echo json_encode($projectsArray);

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}
```

I condensed the function for the sake of saving space. So I just put .... where the variables are being set, as well as where the wp_query args are set, as that all works just fine.

So the question is, how do I output the list of titles, yet return the json array at the same time? And then use that json array to execute a javascript function to add markers on the map? I know how to used the json info to add the markers, just not how to access it in a javascript function that is called by an ajax success. Any help would be appreciated, as I am stuck after searching all over for an answer.

EDIT: Adding the photo below to show what happens when I echo both the list of titles, as well as the json encoded array. I do need the list items for the titles to output like that, but I don't want the json array to echo to the screen. I only need to be able to access it in the ajax success call in order to execute a javascript function.[image: Website Screenshot]

Comment: Where did you stuck?

Comment: @Roman C I'm stuck at try to return the json array from the PHP function and then access the contents of that json array in the ajax success call. I'm not able to access the json array at all once it is passed back. Is the echo json_encode($projectsArray) the correct way to pass the json array back to the ajax success? and if so, how do I then use the data from the json array to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be useful

You can manage the JSON file with the function `JSON.parse(data)` eg.

```
  var = jsonData JSON.parse (date);
```

In this way  in the variable jsonData  you'll have all  the information organized in the same way they are organized in the JSON file

```
yourTitle = jsonData.title;
yourLat = jsonData.lat;
```

and so on

Comment: I'm a little confused about where to put the JSON.parse(data). Does the that go in the ajax success call? I tried writing the success call like this: `success:function(data) {
    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
    $('#project-list').html( data );
    $('#project-list').fadeIn();
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var myTitle = jsonData.title;
    alert("the title is "+myTitle);
   }`  However, it still isn't recognizing the json data at all. The alert fails to execute because the jsonData isn't recognixed from the lines above.

Comment: Is a problem being caused because in the php function I am echoing a series of <li>'s for the titles, and then I'm also echoing the json array? Thus, when the data is returned, it is returning both? Do I have to separate them somehow on the return to the ajax success?

Comment: Edited the original question to show a photo of what is happening when I echo the titles, as well as the json array. I do need to echo the titles, but I only want to pass the json array, not output it to the screen.

Comment: First the JSON.parse(data) must go in ajax success call.

Comment: Second in your PHP code you echo an html code ` echo '<li>'.the_title().'</li>';` this conflit with the JSON format and for this the `JSON.parse(data)` fail. You can not do that here.  The result valid JSON on the server should be only `echo json_encode ($ projectsArray);`. For the list there are other ways, JQuery for example

Comment: The foto show the echo of (data) the value in response of the JSON send by server you need to parse this and not to show this.

Comment: You can separate the list population and the JSON evaluation eg with two ajax call.